# history.popState return different event type in different websites in the same browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history

I am in the process of implementing ajax history on 2 sites. Both of them are working fine using the following code segment:

```
$(window).bind("popstate", function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    /* some logic */
});
```

except that one site's popstate returns a `PopStateEvent` and another site returns `v.Event`

So for the second site I will need to check for `event.originalEvent` instead of just checking `event` on the first site.

Comment: Are they using different versions of jQuery?

Comment: hmmmm good question, very likely!